# SVN Error : “svnadmin: E205000: Too many arguments”

Tags: shell, svn

I am trying to backup my repository using shell command:

```
svnadmin dump $SVN_USERNAME $SVN_PASSWORD $SVN_REMOTE_URL > full.dump ;
svnadmin load $SVN_USERNAME $SVN_PASSWORD $SVN_SOURCE_URL < full.dump ;
```

I am getting the following error:

> svnadmin: E205000: Too many arguments

Answer (score 0):

You are giving too many arguments as the error tells. Generally speaking, all the arguments you specify are wrong.

You don't need to specify password or username for `svnadmin dump` or `svnadmin load` tools. These admin tools access Subversion repositories directly on the file system. There is no authentication in such case; there is no server to authenticate. The only permissions are file system permissions.

Take your time and read the documentation before performing admin tasks:

- [SVNBook | Migrating Repository Data Elsewhere](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate)
- [SVNBook | Repository Backup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup)